# Brightness problem on 22.04 LTS Amd ryzen 5600 with radeon graphics and NVIDIA RTX 3050

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, brightness, amd-ryzen

After installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my DELL g15 5515 (With Amd ryzen 5600 with radeon graphics and NVIDIA RTX 3050 configuration) I installed the nvidia drivers 510.
I'm not able to change the brightness screen using the top right menu slider and also using the fn keys of my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop and just found a workaround \o/

add acpi_backlight=video to your /etc/default/grub file **and then run sudo update-grub**

You can open the grub settings with this command: **sudo nano /etc/default/grub**

Your grub file needs to be like this::

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_DISALBE_OS_PROBER=”false”
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=video"
```

Comment: this solution did not work for me

Comment: after updating the file and running the sudo update-grub you already restarted your system?

Comment: yes of course but nothing changed. But I have a Lenovo Legion 7 with NVIDIA RTX 2070.

Comment: It worked for me thanks @Lucasljj

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help someone searching too for a solution. So i've just discovered that there is a tool to manage your OS's EFI System Partition (ESP). It's called kernelstub.
You can find the official repo here: [Official Repo](https://github.com/isantop/kernelstub)

With the help of this command: sudo kernelstub -a "acpi_backlight=video"
I was able to make it work on, ZorinOS, Ubuntu, PopOs and Kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of an old post, but seeing as I had the same issue on my machine, hope this helps more people.

Try adding the following arg to the kernel:
acpi_backlight=nvidia_wmi_ec

Comment: That would be a good comment but is not an answer.

Comment: So ... Did you try it? Was it useful? Are you having any issue after adding it?